# Django MoneyField: Invalid value for MoneyField

Tags: python, django

I'm having slight of a problem while using MoneyField in Django.

I have 2 models: `Work` and `Price`. And `Price` gets `Work id` as a Foreign Key.

In Postman I'm trying to post a `Work` with a `Price`, but I keep getting an error.

Here is my `work_model`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Work(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

And here my `price_model`

```py
from django.db import models
from .model_work import *
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Price(models.Model):
    work = models.OneToOneField(Work, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='price')
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4, default_currency='USD', null=True)
    shipping = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.price)
```

When I'm posting a `Work` in Postman:

```json
{
    "user":"2",
    "name":"work 20",
    "price": 
        [
            {
                "price":20,
                "price_currency":"USD",
                "shipping":12,
                "total":32
            }
        ],
    "length":"50",
    "width":"60"
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ValidationError at /works/
["Invalid value for MoneyField: [OrderedDict([('price', <Money: 20.0000 USD>), ('shipping', 12), ('total', 32)])]."]
```

I've looked everywhere but can't manage to understand my error, does anyone have a clue?

Thanks for your responses!

UPDATE 1:
Forgot to put the `serializers`.

Here is my `work_serializer`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.model_work import Work
from .serializers_user import *
from .serializers_price import *


class WorkIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer listing all Works models from DB
    """
    user = UserIndexSerializer()
    price_set = PriceDetailsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'price_set',
            'length',
            'width',
        ]

class WorkCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to create a new Works model in DB
    """

    price = PriceCreateSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = [
            'user',
            'name',
            'price',
            'length',
            'width',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        price = Price.objects.create(**validated_data)
        work = Work.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return work


class WorkDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer showing details of a Work model from DB
    """
    user = UserIndexSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = fields = [
            'user',
            'name',
            'price_set',
            'length',
            'width',
        ]
```

And my `price_serializer`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.model_price import Price

class PriceIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer showing Price information when called by Work GET serializers.
    Not showing 'work' field to avoid loop.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = [
            'price',
            'shipping',
            'total'
        ]
        depth = 1

class PriceDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer showing Price information when called by Work GET serializers.
    Not showing 'work' field to avoid loop.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = [
            'price',
            'shipping',
            'total'
        ]
        depth = 1

class PriceCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to create a new Price when new Work model is created in DB
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        fields = [
            'price',
            'shipping',
            'total'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        work = Work.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return work
```

Comment: have you try with replacing the `[]` _list_ inside price, and use directly `{}` dict.

Comment: @SancaKembang Yes, it gives me the error: `{"price":{"non_field_errors":["Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."]}}`